# Track event in analytics - Ajax Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I'm trying to track in Analytics when a form is submitted with success in my website, I'm using an ajax form. 
When i use the console to test the event, works. But i can't figure out a way to fire the event after the form is submitted. I want to trigger this -- > ga('send', 'event', 'contacto', 'sucesso');

This is my ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
          url: "./bin/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {name: name, number: number},
            cache: false,
            success: function() {  
            // Success message
               $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
               $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append( "</button>");
              $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Mensagem enviada com sucesso! </strong>");

            ga('send', 'event', 'contacto', 'sucesso');

      $('#success > .alert-success')
        .append('</div>');

      //clear all fields
      $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
      },
```

Comment: You are using [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075?hl=en), correct?

Comment: are you receiveing any errors in console? also the way you are inserting `<div class='alert alert-success'>` looks uncorrect for me in this part `$('#success > .alert-success')
        .append('</div>');`

Comment: I have no errors in the console, the problem is that i can't find a way to trigger this event from the script. It works fine if i use the console to fire the event ga('send', 'event', 'contacto', 'sucesso');

I want to be able to trigger the code ga('send', 'event', 'contacto', 'sucesso'); once the form is successful submit.